# Specific types from a pack based on position

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

`take_from_args<foo<int, bool, char, float>, 0,2>::type` is to be

`foo<int, char>` based on the positions 0 and 2. The implementation is easy:

```
template <typename Class, std::size_t... Positions>
struct take_from_args;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct take_from_args<P<Ts...>, Is...> {
    using type = P<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>; 
};
```

Now, let's try to apply this to this class:

```
template <int V, bool B, typename... Args>
struct bar {};
```

The problem is the int and bool parameters of `bar`, so it cannot be passed into `take_from_args`.  So let's define:

```
template <int V, bool B>
struct bar_h {
    template <typename... Args>
    using templ = bar<V, B, Args...>;   
};
```

Unfortunately, `take_from_args<bar_h<5, true>::templ<int, bool, char, float>, 0,2>::type` won't compile.  How do I redefine `take_from_args` so that it can template classes like `bar`?

My entire code:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename Class, std::size_t... Positions> struct take_from_args;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct take_from_args<P<Ts...>, Is...> {
    using type = P<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>; 
};


// Testing
template <typename... Args>
struct foo {};

template <int V, bool B, typename... Args>
struct bar {};

template <int V, bool B>
struct bar_h {
    template <typename... Args>
    using templ = bar<V, B, Args...>;   
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        take_from_args<foo<int, bool, char, float>, 0,2>::type,
        foo<int, char>>::value);
//  static_assert(std::is_same<
//      take_from_args<bar_h<5, true>::templ<int, bool, char, float>, 0,2>::type,
//      bar<5, true, int, char>>::value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workaround with `bar_h` does not work because `bar_h<5, true>::templ<int, bool, char, float>` is just an **alias** for `bar<5, true, int, bool, char, float>`:

```
static_assert(// compiles without error
  std::is_same_v<
    bar_h<5, true>::templ<int, bool, char, float>,
    bar<5, true, int, bool, char, float>
  >
);
```

I see two options:

## 1. avoid non-type template arguments in `bar`

- see [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)

**Edit**: As you followed this approach in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46868959/2615118), but I experience [issues with clang](https://godbolt.org/g/MQdbRu): Here is a modified version which [works for me](https://godbolt.org/g/UrmKSk) with GCC 7.2 and Clang 5.0.

```
template<auto...> struct Vals {};

template<class T>
struct HasVals : std::false_type {};

template<auto... Vs>
struct HasVals<Vals<Vs...>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T, size_t... is>
struct take_from_args;

template<template<class...> class P, class... Ts, size_t... is>
struct take_from_args<P<Ts...>, is...> {
// convention: pass-through first argument if it `HasVals`
  using Vs = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
  using type = std::conditional_t<
    HasVals<Vs>::value,
    P<Vs, std::tuple_element_t<1u+is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>,
    P<std::tuple_element_t<is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>
  >;
};

// Testing
template<class Vs, class... Args>
struct bar;

template<int v, bool b, class... Args>
struct bar<Vals<v, b>, Args...> {
    static constexpr int value = v;
    static constexpr bool truth = b;
};
```

## 2. provide more specialization for `take_from_args`

Since you specifically ask for the latter, here is an example:

```
// there could be 1 value(s) at the beginning...
template<
  template<auto, auto, typename...> class P,
  auto v0, class... Ts, std::size_t... is
> struct take_from_args<P<v0, Ts...>, is...> {
  using type = P<v0, std::tuple_element_t<is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;
};

// ... 2 ...
template<
  template<auto, auto, typename...> class P,
  auto v0, auto v1, class... Ts, std::size_t... is
> struct take_from_args<P<v0, v1, Ts...>, is...> {
  using type = P<v0, v1, std::tuple_element_t<is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;
};

// ... 3 ... and more?
template<
  template<auto, auto, typename...> class P,
  auto v0, auto v1, auto v2, class... Ts, std::size_t... is
> struct take_from_args<P<v0, v1, v2, Ts...>, is...> {
  using type = P<v0, v1, v2, std::tuple_element_t<is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;
};
```

Unfortunately, I had no success using `auto...` for the deduction of leading template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Following Julius' last suggestion for redesigning the class `bar`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <auto...> struct Vals {};

template <typename Class> struct HasVals : std::false_type {};

template <auto... Vs>
struct HasVals<Vals<Vs...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename Class, std::size_t... Positions> struct take_from_args;

template <template <typename, typename...> class P, typename VALS, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct take_from_args<P<VALS, Ts...>, Is...> {
    using type = std::conditional_t<HasVals<VALS>::value,
        P<VALS, std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>,
        P<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<VALS, Ts...>>...>  // VALS is part of the tuple in this case
    >;
};

// Testing
template <typename... Args>
struct foo {};

template <typename VALS, typename... Args>
struct bar;

template <int v, bool b, typename... Args>
struct bar<Vals<v, b>, Args...> {
    static constexpr int value = v;
    static constexpr bool truth = b;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        take_from_args<foo<int, bool, char, float>, 0,2>::type,
        foo<int, char>>::value);

    using new_bar = take_from_args<bar<Vals<5, true>, int, bool, char, float>, 0,2>::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        new_bar,
        bar<Vals<5, true>, int, char>>::value);

    static_assert(new_bar::value == 5);
    static_assert(new_bar::truth == true);
    //static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(new_bar::value), int>::value);  // why fails?
    //static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(new_bar::truth), bool>::value);

}
```

Comment: Adding a little debug helper `template<class... Ts>
void inspect(Types<Ts...>) {
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}` (in addition to `template<class...> struct Types {};` and `#include <iostream>` of course) allows us to understand the problem here. Output of, e.g., `inspect(Types<decltype(new_bar::value)>{});` reads ([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ac4177f338d4292)) `void inspect(Types<Ts ...>) [with Ts = {const int}]`.